# C: array of pointers pointing to the same value

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, dereference

I'm writing an IP forwarding program, and I need to splice the following routing table into a `char*` array

```
  128.15.0.0    255.255.0.0    177.14.23.1
  137.34.0.0    255.255.0.0    206.15.7.2
  137.34.128.0  255.255.192.0  138.27.4.3
  137.34.0.0    255.255.224.0  139.34.12.4
  201.17.34.0   255.255.255.0  192.56.4.5
  27.19.54.0    255.255.255.0  137.7.5.6
  0.0.0.0       0.0.0.0        142.45.9.7
```

I have initialized an array of pointers to `char*` like so `char *routing[128][128];`, then I loop through each line, build a `char temp[128]` array which then get's assigned to `routing` as shown below.

In other words, each pointer in the `routing` array will point to an IP address.

```
char *routing[128][128];
char line[128], temp[128];
int i = 0, j = 0, token_count = 0, line_count = 0;
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), routing_table) != NULL){
  // printf("%s\n", line);
  token_count = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++){
    if (line[i] != ' ' && token_count == 2){
      for (j = 0; j < 128; j++){
        if (line[i+j] == ' ')
          break;
        temp[j] = line[i+j];
      }
      i += j;
      routing[line_count][token_count] = temp; //ASSIGNMENT OCCURS HERE
      token_count++;
    }
    else if (line[i] != ' ' && token_count == 1){
      for (j = 0; j < 128; j++){
        if (line[i+j] == ' ')
          break;
        temp[j] = line[i+j];
      }
      i += j;
      routing[line_count][token_count] = temp;
      token_count++;
    }
    else if (line[i] != ' ' && token_count == 0){
      for (j = 0; j < 128; j++){
        if (line[i+j] == ' ')
          break;
        temp[j] = line[i+j];
      }
      i += j;
      routing[line_count][token_count] = temp;
      token_count++;
    }
  }
  line_count++;
}
```

The problem is that every time an assignment happens, it updates the entire array. So when I print out the array at the end, I get the last element repeated.

```
142.45.9.7

142.45.9.7

142.45.9.7

...

142.45.9.7

142.45.9.7
```

I figured I needed to dereference `temp` but that threw a warning and didn't even fix it.

What do I have wrong syntactically? Why are all pointers pointing to the same char string?

Comment: You don't have anything wrong syntactically. You have something wrong logically. You have a two dimensional array of pointers to strings but I can't find you allocating any memory. Looks like you're pointing every one of those pointers at `temp`. How many different strings can `temp` hold at any given time? One, of course. The last one you copy into it. Try assigning `strdup(temp)` instead of just `temp`. The you have to free them all at the end -- best to memset the whole 2D array to zeroes at the beginning so you can see which ones have a valid pointer.

Comment: In `routing[line_count][token_count] = temp;` the `temp` is a pointer, whose object is then overwritten.

Comment: @EdPlunkett that was it! feel free to write an answer and I'll mark it correct

Comment: Have you heard of `strtok` and `strcpy`?

Comment: Done. Delighted it helped. Last time I dared to answer a C question I got beat up pretty hard; we'll see about this one...

Comment: @EdPlunkett there's a chance you will get beat up about `strdup` since it's not standard.  That happens a lot.

Comment: @paddy Thanks, I'll put in a note about that.

Comment: Pointers don't point to values, they point to variables that hold values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right near the end, just before where you increment `token_count`, you've got this line:

```
routing[line_count][token_count] = temp;
```

And that's your problem. `temp` is an array of 128 characters -- what we call a string in C, if there's a null terminator in there somewhere. You're copying each IP address string into it in turn, and then for each one, you assign `temp`'s address to a slot in one of your big two dimensional array of pointers. All those pointers, but they're all pointing to the same actual buffer.

So at the end of the loop, they all point to the last string you copied into `temp`. That's not what you want, and if `temp` is a local in a function, then you're in real trouble.

What you want is either a two dimensional array of actual char arrays (16 chars each would suffice for a dotted quad and a null terminator) -- but I'm a little rusty on C and won't risk leading you astray about how to declare that -- or else you need to allocate new memory for each string in your existing two dimensional array. You'd do that like so, in many C implementations:

```
routing[line_count][token_count] = strdup(temp);
```

`strdup()` is a handy function that allocates sufficient memory for the string you give it, copies the string into that memory, and returns a pointer to it. But it's not part of the standard, so can't be counted on in all cases. If you're writing for one compiler and it's there, you're all set (this is often the case). But if you may have any concerns about portability, [here's a portable way to do the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/481685/424129).

Portable or not, you're allocating memory now, and when you're done with the routing table, you'll need to free the allocated memory by calling `free(routing[i][j])` on every one of those pointers that you got back from `strdup()` (or from some other, more portable function).

To that end, you should call this before allocating anything:

```
memset(routing, 0, sizeof(char) * 128 * 128);
```

...where 128 and 128 are the two dimensions of the array (which I would put in `#defined` constants that I used for the loop and for the declaration, if I really had to do this in C, and didn't allocate the whole mess dynamically). If you first set the whole thing to zeroes, then every pointer in there starts out as `NULL`. Then when you loop through it to free the memory, you can just loop through each "row" freeing each pointer until you hit a `NULL`, and then stop.

Answer (score 2):

Thinking about another approach, it is always error-prone to parse ip addresses of command line output, like ifconfig, route, ip etc etc, so why not use the programmatic way to obtain the routing table information? For example, on Linux, RTNETLINK is the standard way to manipulate route table:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/rtnetlink.7.html

It gives you all the information in well defined struct.

On windows, you can use Win32 API to do the same:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365953(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That is actually a really good idea. However this is for a University course and we have strict specifications like using the provided binary file. I will keep this in mind for the future though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
routing[line_count][token_count] = temp; //ASSIGNMENT OCCURS HERE
```

The contents of the `temp` array may be different at each iteration.

The address of the `temp` array is constant throughout the execution of the program.

So you are obviously assigning the same value to every entry in the `routing` array.