# Why can't I change the pointer's content when in a loop?

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, c-strings

I'm given a string and i need to  display all strings that can be formed removing one letter at a time.
For example,for "abbc" i should display "bbc"
                                        "abc"
                                        "abc"
                                       and "abb"
Here is my code:

```
int main()
{
    char s[41]="abbc",*p;
    int n=strlen(s);
    p=s;
    int i=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
        strcpy(p+i,p+i+1);
        cout<<p<<" ";
        i++;
        strcpy(p,s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It keeps showing **bbc bc bc bc** as if `strcpy(p,s);` wasn't wrote. Why can't I give a value to the `pointer p` in a loop?

Comment: this is not a `C++`. Besides one line (`cout<<p<<" ";`) this is pure `C`. [Link for your teacher](https://youtu.be/YnWhqhNdYyk).

Comment: p and s is pointing to the same memory, so after the first loop n is no longer valid.. not sure why you would expect something different?

Comment: You're not actually copying `s`. `p` just points to the same original string, so all operations on `p` modify `s`. You want to make an actual (deep) copy of the string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a copy of a char\*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/481673/make-a-copy-of-a-char)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

p and s is pointing to the same memory.  The memory is modified at each loop, so after the first loop n is no longer valid as the length of the string.

loop 1: p & s = "abbc", i=0, n=4
   p+0 points to "abbc", p+1 points to "bbc"
   value of s after strcpy(p+0, P+1) is "bbc"

loop 2: p & s = "bbc", i=1, n=4
   p+1 points to "bc", p+1+1 points to "c"
   value of s after strcpy(p+1, P+2) is "bc"

loop 3: p & s = "bc", i=2, n=4
   p+2 points to null or "", p+3 points to something after string
   value of s after strcpy(p+2, p+3) is undifined but likely remaining "bc"

loop 4: nothing treally change from above as you now are outside string

Answer (score 0):

To output substrings of a string according to your description there is no need to change the original string.

This call

```
strcpy(p+i,p+i+1);
```

has 1) undefined behavior (because the ranges are overlapped) 2) and changes the original string.

This call

```
strcpy(p,s);
```

does not make sense because the string is copied into itself due to this assignment

```
p=s;
```

The task can be done using ordinary for-loops. For example (a C++ program)

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    const char *s = "abbc";

    for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; s[j] != '\0'; j++ )
        {
            if ( j != i ) std::cout << s[j];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
bbc
abc
abc
abb
```

Or (a C program)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    const char *s = "abbc";

    for ( size_t i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; s[j] != '\0'; j++ )
        {
            if ( j != i ) putchar( s[j] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure C version. It removes the last character from the string and stores it. After that it replaces each character with the one that came after it, until all have been replaced. At the end the string will contain the substring starting at the second character.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char s[41] = "abbc";
    int n;
    char c, tmp;

    n = strlen(s);
    c = 0;
    while( n > 0 )
    {
        n--;
        tmp = c;
        c = s[n];
        s[n] = tmp;
        printf( "%s\n", s );
    }
    return 0;
}
```